# Using Typeable to partially apply function at run-time (any time types match)

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

Generic programming time!

If I have a function:

```
f :: a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> ... -> an
```

and a value

```
v :: aX   -- where 1 <= x < n
```

Without knowing at compile time which of the arguments of `f` the value `v` is the right type for (if any), can I partially apply `f` to `v`? (using Typeable, Data, TH, or any other trick)

Slightly more solidly, can I construct the function `g` (below) at run-time?  It doesn't actually have to be polymorphic, all my types will be monomorphic!

```
g :: (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> a5) -> a3 -> (a1 -> a2 -> a4 -> a5)
g f v = \x y z -> f x y v z
```

I know that, using Typeable (`typeRepArgs` specifically), `v` is the 3rd argument of `f`, but that doesn't mean I have a way to partially apply `f`.

My code would probably look like:

```
import Data.Typeable

data Box = forall a. Box (TyRep, a)

mkBox :: Typeable a => a -> Box
mkBox = (typeOf a, a)

g :: Box -> Box -> [Box]
g (Box (ft,f)) (Box (vt,v)) = 
    let argNums = [n | n <- [1..nrArgs], isNthArg n vt ft]
    in map (mkBox . magicApplyFunction f v) argNums

isNthArg :: Int -> TyRep -> TyRep -> Bool
isNthArg n arg func = Just arg == lookup n (zip [1..] (typeRepArgs func))

nrArgs :: TyRep -> Int
nrArgs = (\x -> x - 1) . length . typeRepArgs
```

Is there anything that can implement the `magicApplyFunction`?

EDIT: I finally got back to playing with this.  The magic apply function is:

```
buildFunc :: f -> x -> Int -> g
buildFunc f x 0 = unsafeCoerce f x
buildFunc f x i =
        let !res = \y -> (buildFunc (unsafeCoerce f y) x (i-1))
        in unsafeCoerce res
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with **g**, as far as I can see, and polymorphism does not matter either. Just as you can use flip everytime you have a function and the 2nd argument, you know.

Comment: But I don't have`g` at compile time!  How can I generate it at runtime?  IIRC, I can't pass functions back and forth to/from hint

Comment: Writing the function to apply it via th shouldn't be a problem -- the issue is what sort of value you get back (Dynamic/Box) is, as you realize, your only option.

Comment: A few design decisions are ambiguous here. What happens when more than one argument has the same type? Should you always pick the first, the last, or should you be required to specify the argument number? The best way, imho, would be partial application fused with python-like keyword args, but that would require a lot more magic.

Comment: Dan: If more than one argument has the same type I want all possible functions the result from partially applying `f` with a single `v` in each argument placement that is type-correct.  If you look at `g` in my last code snippet you'll see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to write the whole solution here for now, but I'm sure this can be done purely with `Data.Dynamic` and `Typeable`. The source for `dynApply` and `funResultTy` should provide the key elements:

```
dynApply :: Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Maybe Dynamic
dynApply (Dynamic t1 f) (Dynamic t2 x) =
  case funResultTy t1 t2 of
    Just t3 -> Just (Dynamic t3 ((unsafeCoerce f) x))
    Nothing -> Nothing


funResultTy :: TypeRep -> TypeRep -> Maybe TypeRep
funResultTy trFun trArg
  = case splitTyConApp trFun of
      (tc, [t1,t2]) | tc == funTc && t1 == trArg -> Just t2
      _ -> Nothing
```

To keep things simple, I'd have `type Box = (Dynamic, [Either TypeRep Dynamic])`. The latter starts out as a list of typereps of arguments. `magicApply` would look for the first matching TypeRep in the box and substitute the `Dynamic` of the value. Then you could have an `extract` that given a `Box` to which all arguments have been magicapplied, actually performs the `dynApply` calls to produce the resulting dynamic result.

Comment: Isn't this just dynamically checking that `x` is the correct type for the first argument of `f` (no flipping / argument reordering)?  If `f :: Int -> Double -> Bool` and `x :: Double` then I wish to combine `f` and `x` to get `h :: Int -> Bool`.  Did I miss the point of your answer?

Comment: @TomMD that's what dynApply and funResultTy do. They're just copy/paste from the library definitions. *how* they do it shows how to extract the full list of arguments to a function, which in turn can be used to implement the solution I sketched below that code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I got around to building an apply function by swinging `unsafeCoerce` around like a blind woodsman.  See the edit if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. Typeable only? How about good old OverlappingInstances?

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies,
UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class Magical a b c where
    apply :: a -> b -> c

instance (AreEqual a c e, Magical' e (a -> b) c r) => Magical (a -> b) c r where
    apply f a = apply' (undefined :: e) f a


class Magical' e a b c where
    apply' :: e -> a -> b -> c

instance (r ~ b) => Magical' True (a -> b) a r where
    apply' _ f a = f a

instance (Magical b c d, r ~ (a -> d)) => Magical' False (a -> b) c r where
    apply' _ f c = \a -> apply (f a) c


data True
data False

class AreEqual a b r
instance (r ~ True) => AreEqual a a r
instance (r ~ False) => AreEqual a b r


test :: Int -> Char -> Bool
test i c = True

t1 = apply test (5::Int)
t2 = apply test 'c'
```